# Any other tutorials like VIM Tutor?

Tags: unix, vim, terminal

In other words, another command-line program that teaches you other terminal functionalities or workflows? Learnyounode is an example, but I'm looking for something that comes pre-installed like VIM Tutor.

Comment: Why does it need to be pre-installed? You aren't going to find anything else like vim tutor that comes pre-installed.

Comment: It doesn't need to be, was just wondering. Thanks though!

Comment: Related post: [Learning Vim after vimtutor(https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4111/778)

Comment: Thanks, @PeterRincker

Comment: you can make your own "workbook" with commands you want to study up on, then just make them read only.  When exiting just use ```:q!```

Comment: Also, use ```man vimtutor``` to find the location of tutor.vim.  The bulk of it is written to compensate for the various languages of many different users that you might want to ignore if writing your own workbook pages.  After you write them, then you can go back once a month (or however often you like) and work through them again to stay sharp.  When you write them the first time, it can be as entertaining and rewarding as working through them later on.

Answer (score 0):

There is one inside of the vim help. Try `:h user-manual`

Answer (score 0):

You can use openvim.com. I find this website is very useful when I new to vim.